# Function and calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Why do we study function before calculus? Infact what is the necessity of it. Like the domain and range and others thing which is discussed in any calculus book like howard anton or thomas calculus? Another question is, All of the equations are discussed in calculus are only function? Or it may be the equation of non-function also?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you rigorously define derivatives without mentioning the word "function"?

Comment: If we didn't need functions in calculus, how would we define limits, integrals, derivatives, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Newton had only an intuitive notion of a function when he doscovered calculus alongside Liebniz.

The modern notion only slowly developed. And in fact, there are variants of this which are not well known.

A function is a rule transforming the domain into some subset of the codomain. Its usually designated by a function name. Although there are anonymous function conventions too, for example prominently in the Lambda Calculus.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further as to why functions are needed in calculus?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mathematics pedagogy person, so this is just my personal impression.

Calculus can indeed be performed on an equation that isn't a function; for example, we can take the derivative at a point on the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$, which is clearly not a function on its domain.

Nonetheless, it's easier to learn it with functions; the typical limit expression for the derivative—

$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$

—is arguably easier to understand in terms of functions. You don't have to worry about which slope you're taking (from a geometric perspective) if it's a function, which you might be worried about if you're dealing with a lemniscate:

[image]

And functions are arguably the things historically that motivated the development of calculus: the quadrature of functions, the slope of functions, etc. All in all, I think it's good to deal with functions first, and to understand them in terms of the basics of real analysis: limits, continuity, and the like.